# angularjs: input with ng-model tag does not appear in model until I type in it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, null, initialization

Why do properties not appear in the model until a user types in the field?

I have a very simple form:

```
<form ng-controller="CtrlApplicantInfo as vm">
<input id="Name" name="Name" ng-model="vm.ApplicantInfo.Name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name"  />
<input id="Age" name="Age" ng-model="vm.ApplicantInfo.Age" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Age"  />
</form>
```

And a controller:

```
myApp.controller('CtrlApplicantInfo', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$filter', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $filter) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.$watch("vm.ApplicantInfo", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log("something has changed");
        console.log("newValue: " + JSON.stringify(newValue));
        console.log("oldValue: " + JSON.stringify(oldValue));
    }, true);
}]);
```

What appears in the console is unexpected:

```
something has changed
newValue: undefined
oldValue: undefined
something has changed
newValue: {"Name":"Bob"}
oldValue: undefined
something has changed
newValue: {"Name":"Bob","Age":"22"}
oldValue: {"Name":"Bob"}
```

What I want/expect is the model to be instantiated with empty strings "" or null.

```
newValue: {"Name":"Bob","Age":""}
oldValue: {"Name":"", "Age":""}
```

(edit)
Clarification: I am trying to avoid initializing the model in the controller because it's redundant code - I want the fact that I have ng-model on the input to automatically show up in the model.

Comment: If you don't set any thing intially then how can you expect those value, you need to then define it in controller `vm.ApplicantInfo = {"Name": null, "Age": null}`

Comment: How is this unexpected? If you declare `var myField;` What do you expect `myField` to be?

Comment: `undefined`, I would expect it to be undefined!!!!

Comment: The problem is that the model is the boss - which is great, but sometimes I might want slightly different behavior. Basically I want to tell angular that when the controller loads go find all the ng-model bound elements on the page and make a model initializing everything to "". Again this is all about redundancy - I just described the model using the ng-model tags on my elements - why should I define that all again in the ctrl.

Comment: I ended up setting up my API to allow the angular app to "download" the model which is just taking a new instance of the class and converting it to json - I add that object to the vm and point all my inputs to it - works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to $watch is always difficult to understand. Here is what happens:

1. Angular initiates the scope from your view (set the object and Name, Age to undefined), cause the view creates a reference to the object, your scope don't.
2. Angular detects a change to the Name property set to Bob
3. Angular detects a change to the Age property set to Age